# Custom ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-sqlite

I'm trying to get some data that is stored in an SQLite database and display it in a custom list view.

File `Settle.java`:

```
public class Settle extends ListActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase DB;
    Cursor cur;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settle);

        DB = openOrCreateDatabase("MoneyManager.db",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

        cur = DB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Money",null);

        String[] columns = new String[] {cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("name")),Double.toString(cur.getDouble(cur.getColumnIndex("amount")))};           
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.settle_name,R.id.settle_amount};

        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.settle_entry, cur, columns, to);

        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        DB.close();
    }
}
```

File `Settle_entry.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settle_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settle_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My [database schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) is

- Name - VARCHAR
- Amount - REAL
- Reason - VARCHAR

How do I go about fetching data from the SQLite database and displaying it in the Custom `ListView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your database is already created and populated, your code should work just by changing the columns array:

```
String[] columns = new String[] {"name","amount"};
```

Anyway, I suggest you to implement some mechanism (that is,  an AsyncTask) for loading the cursor in the background.

Comment: thanks @rciovati... had to work on the code a bit and got it to work !!